# How can I create automation test for windows applications with java like Tosca does?

Tags: java, windows, maven, selenium, tosca

I need to create an automation test for a Windows application, this test will be created with java platform.

I familiarized with selenium in java but selenium only can test web applications.

I will use java 8 version with maven.

What library recommends me?

I tried find libraries to manipulate Windows object with no result, I'll tried to use autoit scripts for Windows but I can only use precreated scripts, with no posibilities to send commands to autoit from java application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WinApp Driver. I used it to create test automation framework in java (from scratch)  for Windows applications at work. Here are some helpful links:
 https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver

It has video links by msn as well